# Drawing pixels based on mouse position

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, pixel, paint

**Scenario:**

- I have an area on the browser screen *n* x *n* in size (500px x 500px for example, ie 250,000 pixels).
- As the mouse rolls over the area, it "paints" the pixels it passes.
- Percentage of filled/unfilled pixels are displayed
- *Optional advanced scenario*: As the mouse rolls over already painted pixels will "unpaint" those pixels, or paints those pixels in a different colour.

**Solutions/Issues**

- What would be the most efficient way of detecting, logging and displaying the scenario?
- The defined area could be a div, spacer image, image map, table, canvas?
- How would the pixels be drawn?

  - image or div created for every mouse movement
  - server-side image created based on pixel co-ordinates?
- Is it too inefficient to pass the mouse position(s) every time the position changes?
- What would be an efficient way of displaying 250,000+ dynamic pixels/objects/data?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [my recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815512/tablet-pc-jquery-widget-extension-or-browser-plugin-for-drawing-into-website) for the drawing on canvas part, I got a number of good answers.